# Css styling links inside a table (table data ) won't work

Tags: html, css

I have a site made of table for its layout but the links can't be styled correctly

My table code for the navbar

```
<table id="table">
<tr class="navbar">
<td><a href="#">HOME</a></td>
<td><a href="#">MY PROFILE</a></td>
<td><a href="#">MY WORKS</a></td>
<td><a href="#">ABOUT SITE</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My CSS code

```
a.navbar:link {
    color:whitesmoke;

}

a.navbar:visited {
    color:red;

}

a.navbar:hover {
    color:red;
    background-color: yellow;

}

a.navbar:active {
    color:red;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selectors are not correct as the links do not have the class `navbar`.

A correct solution would be to select an element of type `a` within an element of class `navbar` like this:

```
.navbar a:link {
    color:whitesmoke;
}

.navbar a:visited {
    color:red;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color:red;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.navbar a:active {
    color:red;
}
```

Why this use of html tables in general might not be the best option possible is extensively [discussed on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/3346612)

Answer (score 1):

Switch it around:

```
.navbar a { *styles* }
```

Answer (score 1):

a.navbar selects `a` elements that have the class `navbar`. You have to use `.navbar a {}` in this case.

I would not use tables as menus by the way. I recommend using `ul`s instead since they can be styled more sophisticatedly.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.navbar > td > a:link {...}
```

etc.